# Are webhooks needed in Gitlab for triggering a build on tags push

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner

I would like to trigger a Build on Gitlab when a Git Tag is pushed to the repository. At the same time I would like to increment the version number on a file located on the repository before building it on a runner.
My question is . Is it a webhook needed for the purpose ?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a webhook.

You can use the `tags` keyword with the [`only/except`](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#onlyrefs--exceptrefs) condition syntax for running jobs in a pipeline.

You then need to implement the job of course, which will do what you need:

1. take the new tag
2. update a file with it
3. commit the new file and push it back to the repo
4. ... other builds steps ...